# django-storages S3boto3 upload status

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, boto3, django-storage

I'm using django-storages to upload several files using a Model with a FileField in Django Rest Framework. Everything works fine, the frontend aplication just waits until the upload finish and the promise is resolved i the fron while in the backend a database registry is save in the database.

But when the files are too large or there is network issues, the promise just time out and the upload sometimes is done and sometimes is not, and sometimes it uploads the file without loading the link to the database.  Is there any way to generate a progress indicator that shows me the upload status, I could request for the status with my frontend aplication, with a recursive request instead of a Promise that is timed out. Is there is any other sugestion i am open to hear one.